# How to Compute Confidence Intervals in R for Simple Data

Tags: r, statistics, r-markdown

I am in an intermediate Statistics that uses R very heavily. The most recent assignment gave us a list of fat content `x` and calorie content `y`.
The problem I was struggling with asked for the calorie count of a hamburger with a fat content of 38. The problem was asking specifically for a 95% confidence interval in interval notation, which I found.

This is the code I have so far:

```
x = c(19, 31, 34, 35, 39, 39, 43)
y = c(410, 580, 590, 570, 640, 680, 660)

plot(x, y, xlab = "Fat Content",
     ylab = "Calories")


lspeed <- lm(y~x)
summary(lspeed)

plot(x, y, xlab = "Fat Content", 
     ylab = "Calories") + 
abline(lspeed, col = "red")
```

The first two problems were straight-forward. I am currently stuck on the third problem and beyond that.

```
qt(1.95/2, df = 5) #This was a quick way of getting the t-values.
b_0 = 210.954
SE_b_0 = 2.571*(50.10)
b_1 = 11.056
SE_b_1 = 2.571*(1.43)
```

I reached out to the professor, and they were totally alright with me using rounded values directly.

Mehmet

Comment: I think I figured out how to compute the confidence interval properly from the notes that I have: CI = b_0 +- t * SE(b_0). And the same equation is used to find b_1. I was wondering if there was a way to pull something from the summary function's output? For instance, how would I pull my values for the intercept and the slope?

Comment: Please clean up your question, delete everything and leave only a specific problem, and please do not ask several questions, create one question per problem

Comment: You deleted the screenshot of your assignment, so now it's unclear what "the third problem" is

Comment: I made the changes in the post to reflect that question. Please let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the coefficient of determination:

```
summary(lspeed)$r.squared

summary(lspeed)$adj.r.squared
```

will get you the Q4.

Comment: I completely forgot about the `$` operator to access something! I finally figured out the rest of the assignment and I got it turned in! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding pulling the values for the intercept and the slope: the output of the linear model is a list
(see `str(lspeed)`) so you can simply assign them to a vector with

```
cfs <- lspeed$coefficients
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to accomplish! I totally forgot about saving it the values in a vector! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Great, I'm happy I could help! You're welcome! :)